# auto-injected Laravel model has no attributes

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, dependency-injection, eloquent

I'm new to Laravel. I have created a model, a resource controller, and a route for one of my tables, I have modified the model class to use a particular table name, but the model object injected by Laravel 5.4 has no attributes even though a corresponding record exists in the database. Here are the steps I took.

1) Create the model with artisan. I ran this command:

```
php artisan make:model Tree
```

2) Modify the Tree model class as [instructed](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#defining-models) to specify a specific table. I had to do this because my table is named **tree**, not the "trees" as Laravel would otherwise assume based on its internal rules.

```
/**
 * The table associated with the model.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $table = 'tree';
```

3) Create a resource controller that makes use of my model with this command

```
php artisan make:controller CategoryController --resource --model=Tree
```

4) Add a resource route routes/web.php in order to map a web server path onto the controller:

```
Route::resource('categories', 'CategoryController');
```

5) Modify the **show()** method of the CategoryController to var_dump the injected $tree object. It looks like this:

```
/**
 * Display the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  \App\Tree  $tree
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function show(Tree $tree)
{
    // we need to display the children of $tree
    var_dump($tree);

}
```

6) My table structure follows all the conventions [specified](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#defining-models) by Laravel docs. There is an integer **id** column that is unsigned & auto-incrementing. I have the created_at and updated_at timestamps. The only thing different is that the table name is "tree" and not "trees", but that should be covered with the change I made above:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tree` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `parent_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `label` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `display_order` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `forum_id` int(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `url` varchar(128) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `flavor` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `parent_pkey` (`parent_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

This table contains data. It *most definitely* has a record with id=1.

7) I visit the url which should activate the show() method of my resource controller. The output I get verfies that this is in fact the method CategoryController::show(). http://example.com/categories/1

Here is the problem.

**The output of var_dump($tree) has no attributes. There is no error, but something is wrong with the injected object**.

```
object(App\Tree)#217 (24) {
  ["table":protected]=>
  string(4) "tree"
  ["connection":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["primaryKey":protected]=>
  string(2) "id"
  ["keyType":protected]=>
  string(3) "int"
  ["incrementing"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["with":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["perPage":protected]=>
  int(15)
  ["exists"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["wasRecentlyCreated"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["attributes":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["original":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["casts":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["dates":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["dateFormat":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["appends":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["events":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["observables":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["relations":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["touches":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["timestamps"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["hidden":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["visible":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["fillable":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["guarded":protected]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "*"
  }
}
```

**Have I done something wrong? How do I get Laravel to inject the correct object?**

EDIT: Someone asked why I was injecting the wrong object in my route. Here is an abbreviated version of the class that was auto-generated in step #3. It clear references the Tree class and code-hints it is expecting a tree object. I did not create any of this code except the var_dump statement. It was all auto-generated by artisan commands expressly as instructed by the docs.

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Tree;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class CategoryController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Tree  $tree
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show(Tree $tree)
    {
        // we need to display the children of $tree
        var_dump($tree);

    }

}
```

Comment: I think the problem is that your `Route::resource()` method expects an instance of the `Category` and not the `Tree`. This is problematic because essentially what is being used is `Route::get('category/{category}', 'CategoryController@show')`. Is there a reason you're using `category` and not `tree` as your resource?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy I did not manually create the controller, model, or route. I followed the instructions verbatim in the docs. If you re-read my post, you'll see that I specified the table name for my CategoryController at creation time. You can also see from the definition of **show()** that the controller is hinting it needs a tree object. I'll add an abbreviated version of the class for clarity.

Answer (score 6):

There is a naming convention on Route Model binding.

Try to change the action call to this:

```
public function show(Tree $category)
{
    var_dump($category);
}
```

**Update:**
I looked in the source and you can also change the parameters name in resource Route declaration:

```
Route::resource('categories', 'CategoryController', ['parameters'=>['categories'=>'tree']]);
```

And use the $tree variable in action call

```
public function show(Tree $tree)
```

Comment: This has solved my problem for this particular issue, and I suspect it has something to do with parameter naming ( see https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing#route-parameters ). Seems completely odd to me. Any chance you could elaborate?

Comment: The naming convention is on the name of the var you inject in the action call, You used categories for the resource route definition, Laravel expect the singular (category) as variable to inject. Have a look here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing#route-model-binding or if you have time look at the Router source code.

Comment: I you want to know more about the routes defined in your app just run this from the console: php artisan route:list

Comment: Are you telling me that Laravel has some logic somewhere that sees the string "categories" in my resource route and converts it to the singular "category" when defining the parameter name?  That sounds abominable.

Comment: This is exactly how it works with resource route. You can always define your restful routes if you dont want to use the laravel naming convention.

Comment: Ewwww! So what happens when I want a model called Tardis? Or Radius? Mathematics?

Comment: then the model would be called Tardis or Radius ... whats the problem?

Comment: @S.Imp Duh, don't you know anything about Rails, er, Laravel?

Comment: @lagbox Intentionally confusing, nice. S. Imp, if a model has an irregular plural form, you can define that.

Comment: I myself am too much of a REAL artisan to dirty my hands with Laravel, but I suspect the Rails idea of "convention over configuration" is true with Laravel as well. So there are probably many Ewww! moments ahead for you.

Comment: not intentionally confusing ... that is the answer to the simple question ... is there some hidden question behind that question that isn't included in the context ?   Eloquent uses conventions but you DONT have to use them as you can override them.   So what part of naming a Model one of those names needs an answer?

Comment: @lagbox with a model named Radius, does Laravel look for a table named radii? radiuses? radiuss? Conversion CamelCase to snake_case and switching from plural to singular form is *really* stupid, IMHO. There's no point of the model is singular to assume the table is plural. It would have been simpler to just give them the same name, dontcha think?

Comment: Yes there is a convention, but you don't have to use it. That is the point.  You can configure the model as the documentation says. If you think the convention is stupid, then don't use the convention :).

Comment: I don't think it's stupid. There aren't many situations where the plural is irregular, but you can specify them as they pop up. Using the accepted conventions will tell you the exact names of files across the project without having to guess. It's sensible. It's also drinking the Kool Aid. Just drink the Kool Aid, you'll feel so much better.

Comment: @Ringo Jim Jones also said to drink the Kool Aid. The pluralization function is a joke. Checkit: http://board.phpbuilder.com/showthread.php?10395501-Laravel-controllers-models-CRUD-and-code-organization&p=11060793&viewfull=1#post11060793

Comment: @S.Imp It seems to me that instead of picking apart an open source library that misses "die" and "flyby", you could have added those definitions and created a pull request. I don't see how the library sucks because it missed those two words. Also, I think Laravel is more like Tang than Kool Aid.

Comment: @Ringo you obvs didn't read the link. The code is poorly written. The pluralization introduces an entirely unnecessary point of confusion. It's self-defeating. And for what?

Comment: Well, I read the post, but it made me realize how interesting my wallpaper is by comparison. I'm just not sure i trust this Weedpacked character, who seems to hate anything Larvel to begin with. He's the Alex Jones of Laravel.

Comment: I don't see the weaknesses you speak of. Wrappers call other libraries all the time.

Comment: Weedpacked must have been smoking seeds when he wrote that post

Answer (score 2):

I also run into this problem. Laravel will follow the convention for naming the parameter.

For example your model is

```
AwesomeCategory
```

Then auto-generated edit method in AwesomeCategoryController will look like this

```
public function edit(AwesomeCategory $awesomeCategory) // This will not load any attributes
```

Change to

```
public function edit(AwesomeCategory $awesomecategory) // This will be automatically loaded with all attributes
```

Comment: Your lines are same

Comment: the Captial C in $awesomecategory. Laravel intercept it as case sensitive

Answer (score 0):

The issue comes in the resource routing. Replace your routing as

```
Route::resource('category', 'CategoryController');
```

Here the route name must exactly match with the controller name. That was the problem.