# No query results for model Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel

I got problem with edit events. 
No query results for model [App\HomeModel] {id}
I really dont know how to fix my problem.
I trying change findorfail to find but still got some problems.
I change findorfail to HomeModel::where('id', $id)->first();
and still i got error: Creating default object from empty value

Controller with edit and update function:

```
<?php
/**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        $event = HomeModel::findOrFail($id);
        $event->start;
        $event->end;

        $data = [
            'page_title'    => 'Edit '.$event->title,
            'event'         => $event,
        ];
        return view('edit',$data);
    }
    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {

        $time = explode(" - ", $request->input('daterange'));        
        $event                  = HomeModel::findOrFail($id);
        $event->name            = $request->input('name');
        $event->title           = $request->input('title');
        $event->start      = $time[0];
        $event->end        = $time[1];
        $event->save();

        return redirect('/home/list');

    }
```

Model:

```php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class HomeModel extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'events'; 
    public $timestamps = true; 
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
      /**
     * Is it an all day event?
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isAllDay()
    {
        return (bool)$this->day;
    }


}
```

Edit view:

```html
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
   
<div class="panel-heading">
 <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">Edit Event</div>    
</div>

<div class="panel-body">
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('/list/edit/{id}') }}">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <div class="form-group">    
                <label for="name" class="col-md-4 control-label">Name Event</label>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control" name="name">
                    </div>    
                <label for="title" class="col-md-4 control-label">Title Event</label>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <input id="title" type="text" class="form-control" name="title">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">    
                        <input type="text" name="daterange"/>
                    </div>      
            <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-4"> 
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                    Edit Event
                </button>
            </div>
        
    </div>
</form>                   
                          
        <script src="{{ asset('js/jquery.js') }}"></script>
        <script src="{{ asset('js/moment.js') }}"></script>
        <script src="{{ asset('js/daterangepicker.js') }}"></script>                                   
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
                
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
            $('input[name="daterange"]').daterangepicker({
            timePicker: true,
                        timePicker24Hour: true,
            slotLabelFormat: 'HH:mm:ss',
            locale: {
                    format: 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:ss',
                                separator: " - ",      
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>              
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Comment: Print `$id` out to the browser and make sure it's correctly set. Then look in the database to see if there's a row matching that ID.

Comment: when i click edit button is correct id but next i saw something like that /list/edit/{id} when i post to datebase

Comment: I had a similar problem where my controller method was receiving an empty model even though I was certain the id I was supplying was in the database. The problem was that the auto-generated routing rules used a different parameter name. You might have a similar problem. Try listing your routing rules? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42543124/auto-injected-laravel-model-has-no-attributes

Comment: ok i fixed it thx

Comment: i just use where and add array to form in edit.blade